# High voltage in transmission line

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, voltage, power

I'm trying to understand why high voltage is used in transmission but I seem really confused by the explanations I read.

Here's what I could make out:

> [image]
> $$P_\text{loss} = \dfrac{ΔV^2}{R_t} = \dfrac{(V_0-V'_h)^2}{R_t}$$
> So increasing $V'_h$ must reduce the power loss in the transmission line. ($R_t$ is the resistance of the transmission line.)

Is my understanding flawed or correct?

Comment: What does your question have to do with a transmission line. A coaxial cable is an example of a transmission line. What role plays the transformer you have drawn in the circuit diagram?

Comment: I understand the OP to ask about transmission over the power grid, not signal transmission.

Comment: I think the $\Delta{}V$ may be confusing you. It refers to the voltage _loss_ from one end of the power line to the other. But the voltage loss depends on the resistance of the wire, $R_t$, and on the current that the load is consuming. If you know the current, $I$, then a more direct way to calculate the lost power is $P=I^2R_t$

Comment: This should have been better posted on EE.SE

Comment: There's another reason besides power loss.   Because the current transmitted is lower, thinner wires can be used which costs WAY less money!!!!   Not everything is about physics. Lol

Comment: $V_{0}$ increases also when you use a step up transformer  since there is more loops, pd is measured with respect to ground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. To be a bit more precise:

You want some power $P_h$ to arrive at the consumer. And, as (ideal) transformers transform voltage and current, but keep the power value constant, the same power is also consumed at the ${V'}_h$ side of the transformer.

The current at the transmission line then must be

$$I_t = \frac{P_h}{{V'}_h}$$

The power loss at the $R_t$ resistance is

$$P_{loss} = {I_t}^2 \cdot R_t$$

$$P_{loss} = \left(\frac{P_h}{{V'}_h}\right)^2 \cdot R_t$$

You see, keeping power consumption and line resistance constant, the power loss decreases with the square of the transmission-line voltage. E.g. raising the transmission-line voltage by a factor of 10 decreases the power loss to 1/100.

Comment: In electrical engineering, we actually have a name for this effect --- We call it the "I-squared-R loss".   The term obviously coming from your 2nd equation above.

Comment: @KyleB In the last place I lived, the power company paid a discounted price for my excess solar power. The discount was calculated based on one ohm's worth of loss.